# Why does drupal_http_request return a 400?

Tags: 8, http-request

I am having issues sending a POST via my module.

In my browser's REST client I get a 200 with

```
POST https://mydomain.com 
username=myuser&password=password1
```

So I know that the service is working fine.
I tried to replicate this call in my Drupal module with

```
$url = "https://mydomain.com";
$data = array(
    'username' => 'myuser',
    'password' => 'password1',
);

$data = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
$options = array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'data' => $data
);

$response = drupal_http_request($url, $options);
```

The response I get is a 400. according to [this](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html) I am not constructing the request correctly.

Question: How should I change my code in order to get a 200?

Note: I am using Drupal 7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably that you are missing the Content-Type header, as detailed [here](http://plosquare.blogspot.com/2010/03/solution-for-post-empty-after.html). For Drupal 7, this should look like this:

```
<?php
$response = drupal_http_request(
 'http://www.example.com',
 array('headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
 'method' => 'POST',
 'data' => 'param1=value1&param2=value2'));
?>
```

Comment: If you want a HTTP client that's a little smarter (adds the correct content type and auto http_build_query for data) and and do things in parallel checkout [HTTPRL](http://drupal.org/project/httprl)